# Windows driver : PreOperationCallback not called

Tags: windows, driver

I'm trying to create a basic minifilter driver using Microsoft examples (PassThough, minispy...), but my MfPreOperationCallback is not called. I tried different contexts (even if I'm not sure to understand how that works...). I tried the PassThrough example and it works very well and it is very similar to my code...

Here is my inf file and my code :

```
;
; KmdfMiniFilter.inf
;

[Version]
Signature   = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Class       = "ActivityMonitor"
ClassGuid   = {b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}
Provider    = %ProviderString%
DriverVer   = 02/09/2017,1.0.0.0
CatalogFile = KmdfMiniFilter.cat

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12
KmdfMiniFilter.DriverFiles = 12

[DefaultInstall]
OptionDesc = %ServiceDescription%
CopyFiles = KmdfMiniFilter.DriverFiles

[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService = %ServiceName%,,KmdfMiniFilter.Service

[DefaultUninstall]
DelFiles   = KmdfMiniFilter.DriverFiles

[DefaultUninstall.Services]
DelService = %ServiceName%,0x200

[KmdfMiniFilter.Service]
DisplayName    = %ServiceName%
Description    = %ServiceDescription%
ServiceBinary  = %12%\%DriverName%.sys
Dependencies   = "FltMgr"
ServiceType    = 2 ;    SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType      = 3 ;    SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 1 ;    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
LoadOrderGroup = "FSFilter Activity Monitor"
AddReg         = KmdfMiniFilter.AddRegistry

[KmdfMiniFilter.AddRegistry]
HKR,,"DebugFlags",0x00010001 ,0x0
HKR,,"SupportedFeatures",0x00010001,0x3
HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance1.Flags%

[KmdfMiniFilter.DriverFiles]
%DriverName%.sys

[SourceDisksFiles]
KmdfMiniFilter.sys = 1,,

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskId1%,,,

[Strings]
ProviderString     = "GUIDONO"
ServiceDescription = "KmdfMiniFilter mini-filter driver"
ServiceName        = "KmdfMiniFilter"
DriverName         = "KmdfMiniFilter"
DiskId1            = "File Change Monitoring Device Installation Disk"

DefaultInstance    = "KmdfMiniFilter Instance"
Instance1.Name     = "KmdfMiniFilter Middle Instance"
Instance1.Altitude = "370000"
Instance1.Flags    = 0x1 ; Suppress automatic attachments
```

Registration.c

```
/**
    Filter registration information
*/

#pragma once

#include <fltKernel.h>

#include "MiniFilter.h"

// Callbacks : list of FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION structures, one for each type of I/O for which the minifilter
//              registers preoperation and postoperation callback routines.
//              The last element must be IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END


CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = 
{
    { 
        IRP_MJ_CREATE,
        0,
        MfPreOperationCallback,
        MfPostOperationCallback 
    },
    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};


// Defines the minifilter context structure

typedef struct _MINIFILTER_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT {
    ULONG Flags;
    ULONG Count;
} MINIFILTER_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT, *PMINIFILTER_CONTEXT;

// Contexts : a context structure is used to register context types
const FLT_CONTEXT_REGISTRATION Contexts[] = 
{
    {
        FLT_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT,                    // Context type
        0,                                          // Flags
        MfDeleteTxfContext,                         // ContextCleanupCallback
        sizeof(MINIFILTER_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT),     // Size
        'ypsM'                                      // PoolTag
    },

    {
        FLT_CONTEXT_END
    }
};

// This defines what we want to filter with FltMgr

CONST FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = 
{
    sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),               // Size
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,               // Version
    0,   // Flags
    Contexts,                               // Contexts
    Callbacks,                              // Callbacks
    MfUnload,                               // FilterUnload
    MfInstanceSetup,                                    // InstanceSetup
    MfInstanceQueryTeardown,                        // InstanceQueryTeardown
    MfInstanceTeardownStart,                                    // InstanceTeardownStart
    MfInstanceTeardownComplete,                                 // InstanceTeardownComplete
    NULL,                                   // GenerateFileName
    NULL,                                   // GenerateDestinationFileName
    NULL,                                   // NormalizeNameComponent
};
```

Driver.c

```
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <wdf.h>

#include "RegistrationData.h"
#include "MiniFilter.h"

// Global data
MINIFILTER_DATA MfData;

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    //DbgSetDebugFilterState(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, TRUE);

    NTSTATUS status;

    MfData.Driver = DriverObject;

    // Registering the minifilter driver
    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &MfData.Filter);

    KdPrint(("MINIFILTER INIT\n"));

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("MINIFILTER ERROR : FltRegisterFilter failed. Code 0x%x\n", status));
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }

    status = FltStartFiltering(MfData.Filter);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("MINIFILTER ERROR : FltStartFiltering faild. Code 0x%x\n", status));
        FltUnregisterFilter(MfData.Filter);
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }

    KdPrint(("MINIFILTER is Filtering!\n"));

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS MfUnload(_In_ FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Flags);

    PAGED_CODE();

    KdPrint(("MINIFILTER UNLOAD\n"));

    FltUnregisterFilter(MfData.Filter);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS MfQueryTearDown(_In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_QUERY_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Flags);

    PAGED_CODE();

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

MiniFilter.h

```
#pragma once

#include <fltKernel.h>

typedef struct MINIFILTER_DATA {
    PDRIVER_OBJECT Driver;
    PFLT_FILTER Filter;
} MINIFILTER_DATA;

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MfPreOperationCallback(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext
);

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MfPostOperationCallback(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
);

NTSTATUS MfInstanceSetup(
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_SETUP_FLAGS Flags,
    _In_ DEVICE_TYPE VolumeDeviceType,
    _In_ FLT_FILESYSTEM_TYPE VolumeFilesystemType
);

NTSTATUS MfInstanceQueryTeardown (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_QUERY_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
);

VOID MfInstanceTeardownStart (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
);

VOID MfInstanceTeardownComplete (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
);

VOID MfDeleteTxfContext(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CONTEXT Context,
    _In_ FLT_CONTEXT_TYPE ContextType
);

NTSTATUS MfUnload(
    _In_ FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags
);

NTSTATUS MfQueryTearDown(
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_QUERY_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
);

NTSTATUS MfInstanceQueryTeardown(
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_QUERY_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
);
```

MiniFilter.c

```
#include "MiniFilter.h"

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MfPreOperationCallback(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Data);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);

    KdPrint(("MINIFILTER PreOperationCallback\n"));

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MfPostOperationCallback(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Data);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Flags);

    KdPrint(("MINIFILTER PostOperationCallback\n"));

    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}



VOID MfDeleteTxfContext(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CONTEXT Context,
    _In_ FLT_CONTEXT_TYPE ContextType
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Context);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ContextType);

    KdPrint(("MINIFILTER DeleteTxfContext\n"));
}

NTSTATUS
MfInstanceSetup (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_SETUP_FLAGS Flags,
    _In_ DEVICE_TYPE VolumeDeviceType,
    _In_ FLT_FILESYSTEM_TYPE VolumeFilesystemType
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( FltObjects );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( Flags );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( VolumeDeviceType );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( VolumeFilesystemType );

    PAGED_CODE();

    KdPrint(("PassThrough!PtInstanceSetup: Entered\n") );

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


NTSTATUS
MfInstanceQueryTeardown (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_QUERY_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( FltObjects );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( Flags );

    PAGED_CODE();

    KdPrint(("PassThrough!PtInstanceQueryTeardown: Entered\n") );

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


VOID
MfInstanceTeardownStart (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( FltObjects );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( Flags );

    PAGED_CODE();

    KdPrint(("PassThrough!PtInstanceTeardownStart: Entered\n") );
}


VOID
MfInstanceTeardownComplete (
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_ FLT_INSTANCE_TEARDOWN_FLAGS Flags
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( FltObjects );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( Flags );

    PAGED_CODE();

    KdPrint(("PassThrough!PtInstanceTeardownComplete: Entered\n") );
}
```

Does anyone see what's going on ?

Comment: your driver is loaded ? FltRegisterFilter is ok ? where error ? `Does anyone see what's going on ` - but how about you ? you see this ? try to see ?

Comment: I have no errors, and yes my filter is loaded and I don't get an error code on the startfiltering function so I guess it's filtering... But the kdprint is not called in my preoperation function so I suppose that this function callback is not called... (I tested my driver by creating a file, the PassThrough example reacts to this event, but not my filter !)

Comment: MfInstanceSetup is called ? what windows version ?

Comment: Mmm no it's not... Even if I read the msdn doc I still don't get what this function is supposed to do...

Comment: this function called when your filter instance attached to volume. if no attach - no and any pre/post operations callbacks on this volume. so you say that exist dbgprint from driver entry and call from here ok, but `MfInstanceSetup` not called ?

Comment: No this function is not called... so my filter is not attached to a volume I suppose... The following KdPrint that are printed : MINIFILTER INIT
MINIFILTER is Filtering!

Comment: I used the command fltmc instances and my driver doesn't appear in the list... But if I load the PassThrough driver, I find it ! So my driver is not attached to a volume :s

Comment: OK I think I found out what's the problem... I have a 0x1 flag in my inf (for instance setting), this is why, I guess, it's not attached to a volume automatically. I check that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem : I had the wrong flag in my inf file. The good one is 0x0 flag in order to attach the minifilter automatically to the different volumes.

```
Instance1.Flags    = 0x1 ; Suppress automatic attachments
```

to

```
Instance1.Flags    = 0x0 ; Automatic attachments
```